# E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

im getting an error when downloading an application from the terminal. The application that im downloading does exist but here it says:  **E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate.** Im using **Ubuntu 22.04** And my pc is **Dell inspiron n5030.**
I also reinstalled Ubuntu but it still did not work. I als get this error while downloading other apps. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable the `universe` repository, where [Wine](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/wine) is located?

Comment: no i didnt, im gonna try it. Thanks

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/wine  will show you it's found in 'universe' (community supported), which is *enabled* by default for *flavors*, but not main Ubuntu ('universe' has lower security & varying support duration)

Comment: It did not download some of the files, plus it still doesnt work

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't nearly good enough for any serious troubleshooting. Did you run `sudo apt update` first? Also please include ALL commands you ran and ALL output error messages in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok ill try all of the possible things to make it work. Thanks

Comment: 70 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Could not connect to az.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (94.20.20.125), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to az.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Failed to fetch http://az.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to az.archive.ubuntu.com:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: is az.archive.ubuntu.com Down?

Comment: So it would seem - try another mirror instead.

Comment: whats a mirror?

Comment: If you're having troubles with a mirror, select another - https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  (You're not using the Ubuntu archive site; you'd not have the `az.` in your URL if you were), but one provided by mirror.datacenter.az

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirror_site